# How communicate DataCollector and EventSubscriberInterface

Tags: events, collect

I want to collect the data taken from the event in my subscriber and then output them in collect function().

```
class MyDataCollector extends DataCollector implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
             EventTypes::LOAD => 'providerLoad',
             ....
     }               

public static function create(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $collector = new static();

        $eventDispatcher->addSubscriber($collector);

        return $collector;
    }
}
```